# Why does proposition 1 in Euclid's Elements not end with "QEF"?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am reading from Heath's translation of Euclid's Elements. Most propositions either end with "QED" or with "QEF", when the first one is used for proving propositions that are not constructions and the second one is for constructions. However, in Heath's translation, the first three propositions (in book one) don't end with "QED" or "QEF", but with "Being what it was required to do". Why do the first three propositions end differently that all the others? Note that in other translations they don't have this issue.

Comment: Obviously, the abbreviations above are not in the [original Greek text](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI1.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Into [Heath's edition of *Elements*](https://classicalliberalarts.com/resources/EUCLID_ENGLISH_1.pdf), the first four Propositions of **Bk.I** end with "(Being) what it was required to do."

The original Greek formula is: *ὅπερ ἔδει ποιῆσαι* that reads more or less "what has to be done".

From Prop.5, see Heath's note to line 48 (page 252):

> As "(Being) what it was required to prove" (or "do") is somewhat long, I shall
> henceforth write the time-honoured "Q. E. D." and "Q. E. F." for *ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι.* and *ὅπερ ἔδει ποιῆσαι*.

Comment: This is common knowlegde even if one has to use google translate, It does not at all explain the axiomatic  approach of Euclid. So  it's  perhaps better to delete my  explanation od our current knowledge of  The Elements.  For the much outdated account of the discussion of the propositions in the Elements see Heath, History of Geek Mathematic, Vol I p, 374.  Γεια σου.